# How to do Digital Painting type of graphics art like in Braid?

Tags: graphics, effect

I'm wanting to create the digital painting type of effect that you see in Braid for a game I'm creating. I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction? I'm most familiar with OpenGL ES 2.0.

I'm wanting to have the background move like Braid does as well.

If anyone can get me started I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The background animation is done through a complicated combination of particle effects (snow, clouds, and so on) and what looks like a layering of many translucent layers that are not only parallaxed; they also slowly scale and rotate to give a feeling of drifting movement. When combined with traditional frame-by-frame animation, this has a very rich effect.

Answer (score 6):

It's not an effect. The art in Braid is hand created digital art. It is time consuming and requires a great amount of artistic ability.

- Learn color theory.
- Learn how to paint.
- Learn how to use raster art programs.

[Here is a page that has a lot of braid art explained, it has snapshots over-time to show the evolution.](http://www.davidhellman.net/blog/the-art-of-braid-index/)

To make the background move like braid, I think you are referring to parallax movement, where an object in the background moves slower than the foreground objects giving the illusion of distance. For that just link the background images to the camera movement, but with a multiplier from 0-1, 0 being infinite distance and not moving at all, 1 moving the same speed as the foreground.

Comment: That blog is a wonderful read.

Comment: Also you have to have a lot of natural talent, and you must have been drawing and painting since birth.

Comment: It's not just the art. There's definitely an effect or two there to make the background drift and animate beyond a simple parallax.